# Opening a new WebBrowser session for Every instance,VB

Tags: vb.net, session, browser

I made a small program in VB. It opens a webbrowser, and I am trying to get it to **not** inherit other's sessions. This way, for example, I can navigate to a different facebook account with every program I launch. Any sugestions appreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem. If you found any solution, please post here!